# Will a threaded post rim brake pad fit my brakes which take a thread-less post pad?

Tags: brakes, pads

I found these pads on Amazon and I really like them, but they are a bit different than my current pads. They are threaded and the ones I have now are threadless. If I tighten them would it fit on my brake?

[Here are the brakes I like.](https://www.amazon.co.uk/d/Brake-Parts-Bikes/Clarks-Hybrid-Integral-Triple-Compound/B005PVLSIM/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1492202820&sr=8-1&keywords=brake%20pads)

[Here is what I currently have.](http://cdn2.bigcommerce.com/server2800/804sw/products/3076/images/325411/BKPD3001__88380.1403959431.210.210.jpg?c=2)

Is it possible to make them fit? Thanks.

Comment: Brakes are the one place you don't want to fail, ever.  Don't take any risks with brakes.

Answer (score 3):

No it won't work well, I would not try it either... is injury worth saving a few dollars? Why not just buy the compatible parts?

Answer (score 2):

More often than not, no.  The pads you have are threadless and use a Canti Eyebolt Assembly to attach them to the brake.  The ones you want are threaded post, and are more commonly found on modern V-Brakes.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible? Possibly... with some "ghetto-rigging" , drilling or the like, but probably also a bad idea. My personal recommendation would be to either stick with threadless post brakes, or switch your brake caliper to one that takes threaded if your dead set on those particular pads.

Clarks does make a similar pad for threadless but they are not the triple compound like those you used as a example, they do however has removable/replaceable inserts which is handy at times and you could probably find a triple compound pad insert that would fit.

Such as these:
[image]
from [Chain Reaction](http://www.chainreactioncycles.com/clarks-70mm-xtr-upgrade-pads-post-type/rp-prod35473?gs=1&utm_source=google&utm_term=&utm_campaign=Chain%2520Reaction-US-PLA-PLA-All-All-SE-Shopping&utm_medium=base&utm_content=mkwid%257Csc6SmFexk_dc%257Cpcrid%257C68603497608%257Cpkw%257C%257Cpmt%257C%257Cprd%257C120070US)

Or Origin 8 also offers decent affordable pads such as these that are intended for wet weather use, but they are a static pad rather than an insert:
[image]
From [Niagra Cycle](http://www.niagaracycle.com/categories/origin8-pro-force-bicycle-brake-post-pads)

What do you like about them? The fact that the pads uses inserts? or just think they look fancy?

Comment: I like the way they look and have heard that the triple compound is good. I get the bike from my job so I don't want to spend much on it. Would these suffice? - http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/2X-PAIRS-CANTILEVER-BRAKE-PADS-BLOCK-BLACK-SHOES-PAIR-BICYCLE-BIKE-CYCLE/381064842582?_trksid=p2047675.c100005.m1851&_trkparms=aid%3D222007%26algo%3DSIC.MBE%26ao%3D2%26asc%3D40656%26meid%3D4574f8d923e54576a69f2cefbcc54d46%26pid%3D100005%26rk%3D4%26rkt%3D6%26mehot%3Dag%26sd%3D251449427960  I forgot to add that the reason I want new brakes is that the ones I have now do not lock up the wheels.

Comment: By the way, I know that this isn't the proper way to stop, but mine take quite a while to stop so I was looking for something stronger.

Comment: @jtr "I get the bike from my job so I don't want to spend much on it"  That is the wrong way to look at it.  You're on the bike and its your safety that is being compromised by bollocksing around with the wrong brake parts.   If your work supplies the bike and requires you to ride it for work then they have a duty-of-care to make sure its safe.   If its part of a bike-to-work scheme then its your problem to make your bike safe.  Saving a few dollars is ludicrous in the grand scheme.

Comment: Also it may not be the pads that are not the issue, it could be that the brakes also need to be properly adjusted. It could be that the cable has stretched and is not functioning at 100% so you are not getting the full power potential.

Answer (score 1):

I would highly recommend NOT doing something like using a threaded pad in a threadless setup.

The threadless setups are commonly called  "Cantilever-Style" because cantilever systems are almost ALWAYS going to use the threadless type of pads, except those that specifically say "Cantilever V-Style." If you look on eBay, you'll find this is true if you search 'Cantilever Pads' versus 'V-Brake Pads'.

Where you said you had trouble stopping because it took "quite a while to stop," I'd say you either have a bad set of calipers, bad brake levers, damaged cable housings or bad housing stops, as there should be as close to zero flexibility in the brake system. The pads should be 1-2mm away from the rim before you touch the brake lever if they're well set up on a decent set of trued wheels. Then, pull the lever until the pads lightly touch the rim. Then, watch the caliper arms and pull the lever as hard as you can. If you are able to see flex that allows the brake to touch the handlebars, buy a new set of brake calipers or a new bike, because too much flex is ridiculously dangerous.

By the way, I HIGHLY recommend changing to V-Brake style systems, as I personally find them far easier to work on. Those pads, the Clarks Elite Tri-Compound, are literally the same ones I use. Be wary that you'll find an increase in the frequency for replacing them, as they're made of a softer material, but note that the power and the reliability that I've had from these pads are well worth that trade-off.

Good luck with either you choose, but please do not try to bodge the two worlds of V-Brake style and Cantilever style pads into one.